# LINQ NHibernate- Why do I get Column 'is invalid in the HAVING clause?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-sql

I want to get the last entries in a table and join them with another table to produce entries which have a mismatch.

I get the following error

```
Column is invalid in the HAVING clause 
because it is not contained in either 
an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause
```

for both CFWD and Balance
when running the following

```
var lastEntries = from s in session.Query<Statement>()
                  group s by s.Customer.Id into grp
                  select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.Id).First();

 var customers = session.Query<Customer>();

 var balances = from s in lastEntries 
                join c in customers on s.Customer.Id equals c.Id 
                where s.Customer.Balance !=  s.CFwd
                select s ;

 foreach (var line in balances )
 {
     ...
 }
```

However, testing the same in [LiNQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) produces the expected results without errors

```
var lastEntries = from s in Statements
                  group s by s.Customer.Id into grp
                  select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.Id).First();

var customers = from s in  Customers select s;

var balances = from s in lastEntries 
       join c in Customers on s.Customer.Id equals c.Id 
       where c.Balance !=  s.CFwd 
       select s;

 balances .Dump();
```

**Update**

The following is the SQL statement generated by NHibernate

```
select statement0_.Id as Id0_, 
statement0_.TransactionDate as Transact2_0_, 
statement0_.RefNo as RefNo0_, 
statement0_.Description as Descript4_0_, 
statement0_.BFwd as BFwd0_, 
statement0_.Amount as Amount0_, 
statement0_.CFwd as CFwd0_, 
statement0_.TransactionTypeId as Transact8_0_, 
statement0_.CustomerId as CustomerId0_ 
from Statement statement0_, Customer customer1_ 
where customer1_.Id=statement0_.CustomerId
group by statement0_.CustomerId 
having customer1_.Balance<>statement0_.AmountCFwd
```

while LINQPad generates the following

```
SELECT [t5].[test], [t5].[Id], [t5].[TransactionDate], 
[t5].[CustomerId], [t5].[RefNo], [t5].[Description], 
[t5].[BFwd], [t5].[Amount], [t5].[CFwd], 
[t5].[TransactionTypeId]
FROM (
    SELECT [t1].[Id]
    FROM [Statement] AS [t0]
    INNER JOIN [Customer] AS [t1] ON [t1].[Id] = [t0].[CustomerId]
    GROUP BY [t1].[Id]
    ) AS [t2]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) 1 AS [test], [t3].[Id], [t3].[TransactionDate], 
     [t3].[CustomerId], [t3].[DocRefNo], [t3].[Description], 
     [t3].[BFwd], [t3].[Amount], [t3].[CFwd], 
     [t3].[TransactionTypeId]
    FROM [Statement] AS [t3]
    INNER JOIN [Customer] AS [t4] ON [t4].[Id] = [t3].[CustomerId]
    WHERE [t2].[Id] = [t4].[Id]
    ORDER BY [t3].[Id] DESC
    ) AS [t5]
INNER JOIN [Customer] AS [t6] ON (
    SELECT [t7].[Id]
    FROM [Customer] AS [t7]
    WHERE [t7].[Id] = [t5].[CustomerId]
    ) = [t6].[Id]
WHERE [t6].[Balance] <> [t5].[CFwd]
ORDER BY [t5].[Id] DESC
```

I have tried rearranging the statements to allow grouping and don't seem to get it right.

Which is the correct syntax  that will prevent the errors?

Comment: When you test in LINQPad, are you running it against the same database?

Comment: Yes. I copied the statements from LINQPad and replaced the pluralized table names with NHibernate replacements.

Comment: Another thing that might be helpful is to post the underlying SQL query that is getting generated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129133/how-do-i-view-the-sql-that-is-generated-by-nhibernate

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was thinking the SQL way instead of objects. The only statement I require is

```
var lastEntries = from s in session.Query<Statement>()
              group s by s.Customer.Id into grp
              select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.Id).First();
```

and add a grouping for all columns of the Statement object as follows

```
var lastEntries = from s in session.Query<Statement>()
              group s by new 
                    {
                       s.Customer
                      , s.Id
                       ...
                    } into grp
              select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.Id).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a matter of a simple typo.

In your example that works in LinqPad, your where clause compares against the joined `Customers`.

However, in your LinqToNHibernate example, your where clause compares against the `s` from `lastEntries` rather than the joined customer `c`.

So perhaps for your NHibernate example, you just need to do

```
var balances = from s in lastEntries 
            join c in customers on s.Customer.Id equals c.Id 
            where c.Balance !=  s.CFwd
            select s ;
```

Comment: Even re-arranging still produces the same exception. Seeing that NHibernate is complaining about grouping, I assume I am required to add a grouping clause on the last statement but I don't seen to get it right.

Comment: It wouldn't always necessarily have to be the last statement that is causing the issue, because LINQ uses deferred execution.