# not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate and I have a problem, because when trying to save to a database it throws an exception:

> not-null property references a null or transient value NHibernate.Entities.Question.Test

How can I change it?

```
public class TestMap: ClassMap<Test>
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        Table("Test");

        Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.Identity()
            .Column("Id");

        Map(x => x.Name)
            .Column("Name")
            .Not.Nullable();

        HasMany(x => x.Question).KeyColumn("TestId")
         .Cascade.All()
        .Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class QuestionMap: ClassMap<Question>
{
    public QuestionMap()
    {
        Table("Question");

        References(x => x.Test)
            .Column("TestId")
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .Not.LazyLoad();

        Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.Identity()
            .Column("Id");

        Map(x => x.QuestionContent)
            .Column("QuestionContent")
            .Not.Nullable();

        HasMany(x => x.Answer)
            .KeyColumn("QuestionId")
            .Cascade.All()
        //.Cascade.SaveUpdate()
        .Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

EDIT: class

```
public class Question: Entity
{
    public Question()
    {
        Answer = new List<Answer>();
    }
    public virtual string QuestionContent { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Answer> Answer { get; set; }
    public virtual Test Test { get; set; }

    public virtual void AddAnswer(Answer answer)
    {
        answer.Question = this;
        Answer.Add(answer);
    }
}

public class Test : Entity
{
    public Test()
    {
        Question = new List<Question>();
    }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Question> Question { get; set; }

    public virtual void AddQuestion(List<Question> questions)
    {
        foreach (var question in questions)
        {
            question.Test = this;
            Question.Add(question);
        }
    }
}
```

Question has Answer, Answer has GivenAnswer and GivenAnswer has SolvedTest. I have no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: Can you add your classes to the question?

Comment: Have you checked that the `Question` and `Test` objects have the correct references to one another prior to saving them?

Comment: @DavidOsborne what do you mean? I'll paste it

EDIT: PASTED

Comment: Paste the code for the actual `Question` and `Test` classes. It would be good to see how they reference one another.

Comment: @DavidOsborne done, but code havent pasted the best. Dont know why stackoverflow edited it this way

Comment: Can you add the code that calls `Save()`? It would be good to see which object you're saving.

Comment: @DavidOsborne Of course

Comment: Reading between the lines, my guess would be that `questionEntity` is missing a reference to `solvedTest`.

Comment: @DavidOsborne so there should be also public virtual SolvedTest SolvedTest { get; set; } in class Question and  References(x => x.SolvedTest)
                .Column("SolvedTestId")
                .Cascade.All();
in mapping?

Becuase it's not workinf so I must have forgotten about something.

Comment: Not necessarily. Does `SolvedTest` derive from `Test`? Can you include `SolvedTest` and its mapping?

Comment: @DavidOsborne Question has a reference to Answer, Answer to GivenAnswer and GivenAnswer to SolvedTest. Of course I'll do it

Comment: Does `questionEntity` have its `Test` property set when `Save()` is called?

Comment: @DavidOsborne No, because when I seIt, only Test is filled and so I makes that my Test goes to the database second time and SolvedTest still throws exception

Comment: you can view the sql generated by nhibernate either by profiling with a local db or setting the nhibernate config value http://stackoverflow.com/a/129153/2084315.  one of the values is marked as 'not null' in the database but is either being set to null or left off the query entirely (defaulting to null).

Comment: ...but `Question` has a `Not.Nullable()` mapping. I think that's what it's complaining about.

Comment: @DavidOsborne thanks ! It's working ! I don't know why I hadn't noticed it before

Comment: @Karolina, good news! We got there in the end. Can you accept my answer so that I'm duly awarded...

Comment: @DavidOsborne of course, done. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ensure that `questionEntity` has its `Test` property set as it's mapped as `Not.Nullable()`.